# how to find what's the error

Tags: debug

I m new to magento and php. while I m learning, try to write some code but unable to find where the error is. for example I m trying to build the grid in admin panel. I have followed the instructions from different tutorials. But could not find where the error is. there is no line or clue in exception log or system log. 
So how to find where the error is or Actually what happening so that I could not see my output. I m using php storm IDE.
On creating Admin panel grid I could not load adminhtml/mymodule.php, what would be the issue?

Comment: what do you get as output? blank screen or what? why do you say you get error?

Comment: Can you provide some code? otherwise we will be shooting in the dark

Comment: @shatthish blank screen...

Comment: @Marius I m concentrating on whole not only on this issue. for entire magento development how we would know where the error is (except system.log and exception.log)

Comment: see this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: @Marius thanks for the link. Could you please provide a best video tutorial for setup debug and how to debug in php storm for magento project. Even I m unclear / unaware on xdebug and remote debugging.

Comment: looking for help!!!